# How can I delete LPR port from win2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, printer

In win2003, "Printers and Faxes" - "Server Properties" - "Ports", I can delete previously added LPR port, but I can find nowhere in win2008 R2 to do it.

How can I delete LPR port from win2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Print Management" Administrative Tool (assuming you have the Print Services role installed on the server) and select the "Ports" node. From there, you can manage all ports, including deleting them. A shortcut to the tool is start >> type `printmanagement.msc`.

Answer (score 0):

Another less intuitive way is from a currently setup printer, go to printer properties,->ports. Select the port you want to delete and hit the delete button.  This is a hack workaround because half the time if you click on a port from the list, it will change the current printer to the selected port.  The trick is to click on the current port and then arrow down to the one you want to delete and then hit delete.  Again, its a hack workaround and Print Management is a much better tool for the job.